# How to apply sticky table header jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web application build on php in which i want to install sticky header on all tables. As the data growing, searches fetching more records which are no visible. I dont know js or jquery much as i am a php programmer.

The structure of all the tables are..

```
  `<table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>..</th>
       <th>..</th>
      <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>..</td>
       <td>..</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>`
```

I have tried to apply some plugin but they did not work.
Please, specify the correct and full steps. And suggest a good sticky header plugin..

Answer (score 0):

This one has the functionality you need.

https://github.com/markmalek/Fixed-Header-Table